# How do I design an event bus to both publish and consume events to an external message broker

Tags: messaging, event

I have an application that needs to publish events to an event broker and consume events from the event broker.

I want to do this with an event bus. This event bus should have one public method: dispatch.

I do not understand how this works. It has been described to me as this: the event bus will publish messages to the event broker, while in a separate process it will consume messages from the event broker putting them on to the local event dispatcher.

How can one method both publish and consume? How does it know which events to publish and which to put on the local dispatcher? How is the consumer internal to the bus and not an external class that uses the bus?

The classes involved seem to be the event bus, a publisher, a consumer, and events.

I am not understanding how these all fit together in one event bus.

Comment: It sounds like you are designing the event bus and its public interface. So you chose to use just one public method, and now you ask us how that shall work? And which parameters will `dispatch` have?

Comment: ... I would actually expect an event bus to have public methods for registering and unregistering callbacks, like "register/unregister", or "subscribe/unsubscribe".

Comment: I will be happy to retract my close vote ("needs details or clarity") after you edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

An event bus only needs to consume *events* and *bus* (send) them to some other system.

So yeah you could make one with only one public method `DealWithThisIncommingEvent(event e)` sending stuff out in response to that event wouldn't need a public interface. eg

```
class MyEventBus : IEventBus
{
    private void sendOutgoingMessage(message m) {...}
    public IEventBus.RecieveEvent(event e)
    {
        //check e matches rules
        //transform e to m
        sendOutgoingMessage(m);
    }
}
```

You could also make one with no public methods, or you could pass in delegates to call if the even matched the rules etc. It depends how generic you want to make it.

Seems to me if you are consuming some queue you don't need any public interface at all unless you want some generic object that you are going to reuse, your queue library probably has wrapped up the hard stuff and you just want some class that applies your rules and links the in and out queues.

```
class MyQueueConsumingEventBus
{
    MyQueueConsumingEventBus(IQueue in, IQueue out)
    {
        in.OnEvent += this.RecieveEvent
    }

    private void RecieveEvent(event e)
    {
        //check e matches rules
        //transform e to m
        out.Send(m);        
    }
}
```